# Whenever I press home on my Gionee s10b or reboot the phone I am stuck with this

Tags: google-play-store

Whenever I reboot or press home on my Gionee, I am stuck on this page, and it doesn't load at all

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled the Google Play Services updates and all was well.
I updated it back though. All was still well